# python[poetry] installation is getting stuck

Tags: python-poetry

[image]

I am using the following curl command to install poetry

```sh
 curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python
```

but poetry is getting stuck as shown in the image. Any help?

Comment: happens when https links get blocked. Resolved as of now

Answer (score 18):

It could be related to the underlying use of pip and the keyring, it happened to me too with Poetry and found that was the underlying cause (see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7883)

My temporary workaround is to disable the keyring by setting an env var.

```
export PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too, my issue was that some dependencies got stuck, so when I ran the installation with `-vvv` it got stuck on

`<internal artifactory>: Downloading wheel: black-22.3.0-py3-none-any.whl`

and running

`poetry cache clean --all <internal artifactory>`

helped.

The installation after wiping cache took long, but actually finished.